# Pymongo - Get a Nested Collection and Updating it

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to find a nested collection in my MongoDB database and update it from Pymongo. Here is how my document tree is structured:

```
{
    "name_list" : [
        {
            "_id" : ...,
            "name" : "Joe Edwards",
            "aliases" : [
                "Allen Dingus",
                "Edward McPickles"
            ]
        },

        ...
    ]
}
```

The collection I wish to access is `aliases`. Currently, my code uses the `find()` function to locate the element in the `name_list` with the `name` key of "Joe Edwards". What I'm getting in return is a cursor object; that is expected. However, I cannot find a way to access the `aliases` collection and update it (I'm looking for something like `db.name_list.find(...)[0].aliases.update(...)` so that I can just manipulate `aliases` directly).

I've looked over the PyMongo documentation and a lot of posts on Stack Exchange as well but I found nothing similar. My temporary fix is just to access the `name_list` and update the whole document belonging to "Joe Edwards", but it isn't really elegant. Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: is `name_list` a field in every document as well as the name of the collection you are trying to query?

Comment: No, its the collection on the highest level in my database.

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB tries to align the operators of the drivers (Pymongo included) with the operators for the `mongo` shell. In the best case, the `mongo` shell operation looks exactly like the Pymongo version of the command. So if you can't find an operator that you need, chances are you may be able to find it in the [Operator documentation page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/)

Regarding your question, depending on what you want to do, there are a couple of options available to you:

**Updating an existing array element**

This can be done using the [`$` update positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

```
db.name_list.update_one({'aliases':'Allen Dingus'}, {'$set': {'aliases.$': 'Alias 1'}})
```

Note the `aliases.$` operation, which will update an alias of "Allen Dingus" and replace it with "Alias 1". With your example document, this will result in:

```
{
  "_id": ...,
  "name": "Joe Edwards",
  "aliases": [
    "Alias 1",
    "Edward McPickles"
  ]
}
```

**Adding a new array element**

This can be done using the [`$push` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) or the [`$addToSet` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/):

```
db.test.update_one({'aliases':'Allen Dingus'}, {'$push': {'aliases': 'Alias 2'}})
```

This will search for an alias "Allen Dingus" and add the new entry into the array. With your example document, this will result in:

```
{
  "_id": ...,
  "name": "Joe Edwards",
  "aliases": [
    "Allen Dingus",
    "Edward McPickles",
    "Alias 2"
  ]
}
```